# How to get IPv4 address of the client instead of IPv6 in Tornado?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I am trying to get the caller address of the incoming requests to my tornado server using tornado `RequestHandler` class `request.remote_ip` variable as mentioned in the official doc: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.remote_ip

I am getting IPv4 address for most of the caller, but for one particular caller I am getting a IPv6 address.
Is it possible to get the IPv4 address of the caller? Is it something related to the requests being framed by the caller which provides only the IPv6 address.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how DNS lookup works. Let me illustrate:

1. Client types in your website's address in their browser.
2. Browser asks the operating system for the IP address of the domain.
3. Operating system makes DNS request to ISP's servers.
4. Since your server supports both IPv4 and IPv6, and the client's OS also supports both, the ISP sends back your server's IPv6 address.
5. The operating system gives the IPv6 address to the browser.
6. The browser makes the request to the IPv6 address.
7. The request is made over IPv6 protocol, so the client also has an IPv6 address.

As you can see, it's upto the ISP to decide which IP protocol should be used. So, if the client is sending a request over IPv6 protocol, they will not have an IPv4 address.

---

If you want to only support IPv4, you should turn off IPv6 for your server.

Check with your hosting provider or remove your server's AAAA record.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote side connected via IPv6, that is all the information available – IPv4 is not involved in the connection at all. There is no general way to get "the" IPv4 address from the IPv6 address: The remote host may have no, 1, or many IPv4 addresses which may-or-may-not have the same reachability as the IPv6 address.

If you want only IPv4 addresses, do not allow IPv6 connections. Better yet, support both IPv4 and IPv6 in your application.